# Unison - how to make it sync automatically (bidirectional)

Tags: 18.04, sync, unison

I have a folder `music` on my HDD and folder `Music` in external HDD. I want these 2 folders to be synced (ie if I add/remove/edit something in one folder, the changes immediately reflects in another).

I think that `Unison` could do this but I'm struggling setting `Unison` to sync **automatically**. For now, I have to manually sync.

I've read that `repeat=watch` should do the thing but I can't set it.

[image]

[image]

As you can see the value "watch" hasn't been saved.

I tried `nano ~/.unison/Music\ HDD\ EXT\ HDD.prf` and manually set `repeat` = `watch` and tried to put some file into one folder but it didn't copied it into another.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem here is a misunderstanding of what the graphical interface can do. You'll see in your screenshot that the `repeat` option is only for the *text interface only*. That is because the *graphical interface* can only run unison once when you click GO.

To get the behavior you want, you'll need to use the text (command line) interface. Since you've put `repeat=watch` in your profile, you'll just need to open up a terminal and run Unison from the command line with that profile:

```
unison Music\ HDD\ EXT\ HDD &
```

I would recommend a shorter profile name than `Music\ HDD\ EXT\ HDD` ;) . The `&` is there to run Unison in the background (detached from that particular terminal). Then, since it looks like you want to run Unison very automatically, checkout [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/427334) on how to run that Unison command automatically when you login.